# Error about "Ambiguous column name"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I just have an example for query in SQL Server 2016: write SQL code which will show values `InvoiceNumber` from table `INVOICE` which includes a value..............

I need to join 3 tables. This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    InvoiceNumber
FROM 
    INVOICE AS I 
INNER JOIN 
    LINE_ITEM AS LI ON (I.InvoiceNumber = LI.InvoiceNumber)
INNER JOIN 
    PRODUCT AS P ON (LI.ProductNumber = P.ProductNumber)
WHERE 
    Description = 'Heather Sweeney Seminar Live in Dakkas on 25-OCT-09 - Video'
```

and this code always results in an error :

> Ambiguous column name InvoiceNumber

on the `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` query

Comment: Specify which column to select, e.g. `I.InvoiceNumber`.

Comment: Please make a more specific title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always qualify all your columns names in a query, especially if it has more than one table:

```
SELECT I.InvoiceNumber
FROM INVOICE AS I INNER JOIN
     LINE_ITEM AS LI
     ON I.InvoiceNumber = LI.InvoiceNumber INNER JOIN
     PRODUCT P
     ON LI.ProductNumber = P.ProductNumber
WHERE P.Description = 'Heather Sweeney Seminar Live in Dakkas on 25-OCT-09 - Video'
```

If you get into this habit, you simply will not ever have such an error.

Answer (score 1):

If 2 tables have the same columns then you have to tell in the query which column you want to use. Do that by adding the table name in front of it.

```
SELECT I.InvoiceNumber FROM INVOICE AS I ...
```

Comment: OK IT WORKS THANK YOU